# Overriding server folder redirection with manual JavaScript redirection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please ignore if I made any noob mistake, this is my first time posting on StackOverflow.

So I was using javascript to redirect inside my react app. I am not using the react redirect library for that though. I am using states to change the current page I wanted to display.

What I did was whenever my app loaded the main component, in the componentWillMount function, I use the window.location.href to get the user's URL and based on that I have different switch case and that changes the state accordingly. Everything worked fine on my localhost.

But after I uploaded the build onto the server, and used my manual redirections, for eg, site_name.com/my_redirect it showed that the link was broken. I am assuming that it has something to do with my server that it is looking for that directory.

```
componentWillMount() {
    let requestedPage = window.location.href;
    this.setRedirects(requestedPage.split('/').pop());
}

// This method updates the url
updateURL(directory = "home") {
    window.history.pushState(null, directory, '/'+directory);
}

// This method updates the state variable to set redirects
setRedirects(requestedPage) {
    switch(requestedPage.toLowerCase()) {
        case "home" : 
            break;

        case "my-story":
            this.changePage("My Story");
            break;

        case "my-works":
            this.changePage("My Works");
            break;

        case "my-skills":
            this.changePage("My Skills");
            break;

        default:
            this.updateURL();
            break;
    }
}

// This method is responsible to change the current page via state change
changePage(pageName, tag = null) {
    if(pageName === 'home') {
        this.updateURL();
        this.setState(
            {
                currentPage: "home",
                prevPage: tag
            }
        );
    }
    else if(pageName === 'My Story') {
        this.updateURL("my-story");
        this.setState(
            {
                currentPage: "about",
                prevPage: null
            }
        );
    }
    else if(pageName === 'My Works'){
        this.updateURL("my-works");
        this.setState(
            {
                currentPage: "projects",
                prevPage: null
            }
        );
    }
    else if(pageName === 'My Skills'){
        this.updateURL("my-skills");
        this.setState(
            {
                currentPage: "skills",
                prevPage: null
            }
        );
    }
}
```

So maybe anyone could help me figure out how can I override this server redirection and use my manual redirection.

Comment: What kind of server is it? Apache has [rewrite rules](https://serverfault.com/questions/188373/apache-2-2-rewrite-force-all-requests-to-index-html) ExpressJS has [sendFile](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) Nginx has [rewrite rules](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/) ...

Comment: I am using create-react-app and react compiler to test it on localhost. Since it's a static site I didn't require Apache.